# VS 2022 coding style options not being applied

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have configured VS 2022 to "prefer this." but the editor keeps removing "this." on code clean-up and suggesting that "name can be simplified" where I use them.

Anyone else encountered this issue?

[image: Screenshot of current settings]

Comment: Do you by any chance have the ReSharper extension by JetBrains installed on your VS 2022 ?

Comment: Does the project have an `.editorconfig` file?

Comment: No ReSharper.
No .editorconfig file in the project folder (is that where it would be if I had one?)

Comment: Just to add to my question: I have the same settings in VS 2019 and it works fine there. (in fact, I switched back to it because 2022 seems a bit buggy to me...)

Comment: Try reporting it to MS and see if they can confirm it's a bug. In that case they'll issue a fix.